# IMG inside container not displaying

Tags: html, css

I have created a container with the intention of two columns floating side by side. One column contains a picture of me cresting the water while scuba diving, and the other is all of the necessary input sections for a contact me box. Below I have a slideshow referencing the pictures stored in the repo exactly the same and it works.

Relevant section of index.html:

```
<!-- Contact Me-->
    <section class="content-section bg-primary text-black">
        <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5 text-center">
            <h2 class="mb-4">
                Have a project recommendation? A job opportunity? Contact me below!
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-container" id="Contactme">
            <div class="contact-row">
                <div class="contact-column">
                    <img src="/assets/img/scuba.jpg" alt="Photo of me scuba diving taken by Ashley White">
                </div>
                <div class="contact-column">
                    <form action="/action_page.php">
                        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
                        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
                        <label for="fname">Company</label>
                        <input type="text" id="cname" name="companyname" placeholder="Your company's name..">
                        <label for="country">Region</label>
                        <select id="country" name="country">
                            <option value="africa">Africa</option>
                            <option value="asia">Asia</option>
                            <option value="aus">Australia</option>
                            <option value="eu">Europe</option>
                            <option value="mideast">Middle East</option>
                            <option value="namerica">North America</option>
                            <option value="samerica">South America</option>
                        </select>
                        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                        <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.."
                            style="height:170px"></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Relevant section of styles.css

```
/* Style inputs */
input[type="text"],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

/* Style the container/contact section */
.contact-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px;
}

.contact-column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  background: color #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px;
}

.contact-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .contact-column,
  input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

There seems to be a difference between running it locally via VSCode's debug and run vs the live version after I have pushed the changes to GitHub. I am hosting the website via GitHub pages on a custom domain (mattharten.com if it is relevant).

My suspicion is that I am limiting the available space within the container and the image I am trying to display there no longer fits. scuba.jpg is a 360 x 640 px .jpg file in the same /assets/img/ location as the other pictures used on the site. I am having no issues with the other images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the GitHub repository for the project was showing "Scuba.jpg" rather than "scuba.jpg" and after checking the files within the actual folder, the image name was in fact lowercase. For whatever reason, GitHub Desktop would not recognize the change & update it in the repository - even when pushing other commits.

**To fix it, I renamed the file to be used, made a copy of scuba.jpg, renamed it contact-scuba.jpg, and referenced the new name in the file. Now it works pretty as can be**

Now it works, I have no idea why GitHub Desktop wouldn't detect the file name case change.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "assets/img/scuba.jpg" instead for your src. There shouldn't be a backslash preceding the first directory. If you replace the src of the image with "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png", it shows up.

Comment: I made the suggested change, I believe tried it earlier as well, but there seems to be no change in what I see on the live version.

Comment: It might be that the image directory is wrong in the HTML. There should be an assets folder within the same folder as the HTML file, but the HTML file should not be in the assets folder.

Comment: The current setup has the index.html file is within the Portfolio folder. The assets folder is also within the Portfolio folder, as is the css folder. Only Portfolio contains all 3 and it is the GitHub Repository folder.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser's cache and refreshed the page?

Comment: I cleared the cache & reloaded the window. I also had my friend access the site from another computer, they see it the same. I suspect the image is too big for the size constraints of either the CSS or because I am trying to float two columns side by side there isn't sufficient room. Learning as I go, so I really don't know yet.